# Exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IllegalName: org/jibx/binding/Compile

Tags: jboss, apache-axis, jibx

The requirement for me  is to run the EAR files in jboss-5.1, which was earlier running in jboss-4.2

So I took the EAR files as such from 4.2 and put that in 5.1 and am getting many exceptions. One such exceptionm, I have pasted below

```
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfszip:/D:/softwares/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ssmscms.ear/common.jar/jibx-bind-1.1.5.jar/
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:177)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IllegalName: org/jibx/binding/Compile
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:477)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:626)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:63)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:572)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:134)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:452)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:251)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:150)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:265)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at org.jboss.deployment.OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.processJBossClientMetaData(OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:115)
        at org.jboss.deployment.OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.processMetaData(OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:82)
        at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:177)
        at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:93)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
```

Am not sure what went wrong .. Do i need to put higher version of jibx-bind jar ?? Please guide me. Thanks in Advance

Regards
Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded JIBX jar files. Earlier the version was jibx 1.1.4. So now I upgraded it to jibx 1.2.1. So now its working fine